# Forming a given word, using the words of a given word list

Tags: python, string, algorithm, data-structures

I have a target_word, say 'aaaaaaa', and also a list of words ['aa', 'aaa']. The question is to find that is it is possible to form the given words using the concatenation of multiple words or at least one word from the list of words. (Every word from the list can be used unlimited times).

Constraints:

```
length of the list of words<=10^3
```

In the above example:

```
aaaaaaa = aa + aa + aaa
```

My approach is to go greedy and check the existence of the longest words from the list in the given word. But I suspect this may not be a good approach.

I sort the list in the order of decreasing lengths of the words.
list=['aaa', 'aa'] and then iterate to check the existence of that word in the given target word.

target_word= target_word.replace("aaa", "")

and continue in a similar fashion.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe tell your approach and ask for improvements `my approach is to go greedy` does not suggest anything specific.

Comment: @YashvanderBamel I added it, please review

Comment: Your approach will give the wrong result for whether we can produce 'baaab' out of the words 'bb' and 'aaa'.  Instead can you produce a recursive algorithm that is slow but guaranteed correct?  And then find a way to not redo the same logic so that it becomes fast?

Comment: @btillyI have thought of the recursion, but that will give 2^1000 order of complexity, which is not practical.

Comment: Have you considered using data structure Trie?

Comment: @AyushTiwari And now for the second part of my hint.  It is only slow because you keep coming to the same conclusions over and over again.  Is there some way to remember the previous conclusion so that you don't have to redo the work?  What does that improve the speed to?

Answer (score 0):

Trie + Backtracking

1. construct a trie with the words in the list.
2. Add the given string to Queue. Set a flag to false.
   till the queue is empty

2.1 take top element as current string
2.2 taking each char in current string search in trie.
2.3 if you encounter an end of word in trie, add the remaining part of current string into queue.
2.4.1 if there is a mismatch or at the last char is not end of word quit comparison and go to next element of queue.
2.4.2 if there is a match till the end of the current string and eod of word exists in trie change the flag to true and quit.

3. return flag